# How Private Ethereum network store my input data in mined block

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to understand how a private ethereum blockchain store data. I connect to a node through web3j API in java and send a transaction like:

```
                EthSendTransaction sendTrans = txManager.sendTransaction(DefaultGasProvider.GAS_PRICE
                    ,
                    DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT,
                    "0xae551c2ae4a15472c62c77cee07cf00467c19b9b",
                    txData,
                    BigInteger.ZERO);
```

where my txData is a hex number convert from a String "This is test Data".
I see the pending transaction:

```
[{
blockHash: null,
blockNumber: null,
from: "0x6a30dd87fb4ce370c4fd4193e5b59b0cc4dc8daf",
gas: 9000000,
gasPrice: 4100000000,
hash: "0x772267cf882ddecdb2eefebeb2b611c109c14c2a1c413a9bfe7f96ec71508a9b",
input: "0xfcc7fd1e5153f1f6b2af143ebdc446815df610b67c9f550095d827d925eb0427",
nonce: 212,
r: "0xe33e228564c60fdba3b8cdf9af4ff814cab93746eb7f350230a3cc1b14cb1865",
s: "0x5630e0476543db3b729f66fe87ee50804d9522cf343c7e4e61b907307ed265ac",
to: "0xae551c2ae4a15472c62c77cee07cf00467c19b9b",
transactionIndex: null,
v: "0x1b",
value: 0
```

}]

where the input : "..." is the data that I want to store. However, after the block is mined, I use eth.getBlock("..."). I received:

```
{difficulty: 131072,extraData: "0xd683010914846765746886676f312e3135856c696e7578",
gasLimit:3144857017,
gasUsed: 23112,
hash: "0x7ed84ceae544a0a8237e75be62ec919b3e096e76bc558f965ae54d4b2b151cb7",
logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", miner: "0x6a30dd87fb4ce370c4fd4193e5b59b0cc4dc8daf",
mixHash: "0x2ad17c7fe0638a87e47b2c9113c401c9c6bfc64bf7fefb3d3edbfdf0246e4742",
nonce: "0x6cfde534ed9015bd",
number: 319,
parentHash: "0xfa4030d2957a079314b10701daa332769430d78982e0467b03c5ab14ee5d25ed",
receiptsRoot: "0xe4d41217d0d481ec201d56b52c665b62cb73e7b4606cb189b31e09a3671d155e",
sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
size: 675,
stateRoot: "0x58b99cab1ae04e204ef6a4339261d7d16a80f115e4a331ef30f66f0be19850d4",
timestamp: 1600853478,totalDifficulty: 41875200,transactions: ["0xcc8084be6574fe26a6045501c231557199c644e0add9ade3a6ba6202408fad56"],
transactionsRoot: "0xdae0f9a664d9fa2c48a344004c20b034e7d125395506eb3ce7d1c1e39aceb4bb",
uncles: []}
```

I'm confusing that how can I get back the string that I store in the block chain.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Using `eth_getBlock()` will return the block data, not the specific tx data that you're looking for. You want the specific data from your tx. Since you have the tx hash (`"0x7ed84ceae544a0a8237e75be62ec919b3e096e76bc558f965ae54d4b2b151cb7"`), my assumption is that `eth_getTransactionByHash()` ([wiki link](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_gettransactionbyhash)) would be your best shot. If not that, you may want to use the [RPC wiki](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API) to try and find a call that suits your needs.